# How do I get rid of this 'jumpy' jQuery behavior?

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, jquery-animate

After you have held still on a button and it snaps down, then you move and the button animates up again. I'm trying to get it to animate up and stay up until you move off of it, then smoothly animate down. I do need this to work in Safari, Firefox and IE.

Thank you in advance for your help, time and consideration.

Here is a working sample of the code.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        var navDuration = 500; 
        var navJumpHeight = "90px";

        $('#tabs li').hover(function() {
            $(this).animate({ height : "-="+navJumpHeight }, navDuration);           
        }, function() {
            $(this).animate({ height : "150px" }, navDuration);
        });        
    });
    // --></script>

    <style type="text/css"><!--
    /* CSS Reset */
    html,body,div,ul,ol,li,dl,dt,dd,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,p,blockquote,fieldset,input,hr{margin:0;padding:0;line-height:1em;}
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,address,caption,cite,code,em,strong,th{font-size:1em;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;line-height:1em;}
    ul,ol{list-style:none;}
    fieldset,img,hr{border:none;}
    q:before,q:after{content:'';}
    abbr,acronym{border:0;}
    caption,th{text-align:left;}
    table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
    td {vertical-align:top;}
    html{font-size:100.01%;}
    body{font-size:1em;}
    a img{border: none;}

    body{ font-family:Arial; font-size:10px; font-weight:500; background:#ffffff no-repeat center top; }    
        div.headerblock{ position:absolute; display:table-cell; text-align:center; left:0px; top:0px; width:100%; height:150px; }   
            div.header{ position:relative; width:900px; height:170px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }
                div.logo        { position:relative; display:table-cell; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; left:0px; top:0px; width:349px; height:170px; float:left; }


        #headerblock #header #tabs { height: 150px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0 10px; left:40; list-style: none; position: relative; filter:alpha(opacity=85); opacity:0.85; }
        #headerblock #header #tabs li, #headerblock #header #tabs li a { width: 100px; position: relative; float: left; }      
        #headerblock #header #tabs li { top: 0 px; margin: 0; background: none; padding: 0; display: block; vertical-align: bottom;}
        #headerblock #header #tabs li a { display: block; color: #ffffff; font-size: 1.7em; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; height: 150px; line-height: 1.1em}
        #headerblock #header #tabs #tab_about a   { background-color: #ff0000; }
        #headerblock #header #tabs #tab_services a{ background-color: #ffa500; }
        #headerblock #header #tabs #tab_contact a { background-color: #ffff00; }
        #headerblock #header #tabs #tab_learning a{ background-color: #00ff00; }
        #headerblock #header #tabs #tab_clients a { background-color: #0000ff; }
    --></style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="headerblock" id="headerblock">
    <div class="header" id="header">
        <div class="logo">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <ul id="tabs">
            <li id="tab_about"><a href="#">&nbsp;<br>Tab 1</a></li>
            <li id="tab_services"><a href="#">&nbsp;<br>Tab 2</a></li>
            <li id="tab_contact"><a href="#">&nbsp;<br>Tab 3</a></li>
            <li id="tab_learning"><a href="#">&nbsp;<br>Tab 4</a></li>
            <li id="tab_clients"><a href="#">&nbsp;<br>Tab 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I put this in a jsFiddle so people can play around with it: http://jsfiddle.net/PbGaK/

Answer (score 1):

Ad an `overflow: hidden` to the `li`s because jQuery is doing that during animation as well: http://jsfiddle.net/UJSZq/.

```
#headerblock #header #tabs li { overflow: hidden }
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up I really appreciate at it.